# Simpler alternative to inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join, union, reconciliation

Is it possible compare data from 2 tables in one table?

table 1

| ID | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann |
| 2 | Ben |

table 2

| ID | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann |
| 3 | Cyc |

output

| ID | Val1 | Val2 | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ann | Ann | 1 |
| 2 | Ben |  | 0 |
| 3 |  | Cyc | 0 |

UNION stacks queries on top, so one would end up with 4 rows (1,2,1,3). And INNER JOIN may not be the best solution since we do not know which table is longer?

```
(SELECT t1.id, t1.val, new.sum_val, t1.val = new.sum_val as Match
FROM t1

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT t2.id, SUM(t2.val) as sum_val
FROM t2
WHERE t2.date = TODAY()
GROUP BY t2.ID) new on t1.ID = t2.ID

WHERE t1.date = TODAY())
```

Comment: Try FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a *full join*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a full join. That's roughly a left and a right join in one. It retains all rows from both table. If there's a matching partner row, the partner rows are combined, if not the values for the partner row stay `NULL`.

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
       t1.val AS val1,
       t2.val AS val2,
       CASE
         WHEN t1.val = t2.val
               OR t1.val IS NULL
                  AND t2.val IS NULL THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END AS match
       FROM "table 1" AS t1
            FULL JOIN "table 2" as t2
                      ON t2.id = t1.id;
```